# VSCode: disabling markdown preview auto-refresh?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to disable markdown preview auto-refresh?

One particular use case I have in mind:

1. I have markdown files A.md and B.md open in VSCode.
2. Active tab is A.md.
3. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to open the preview for A.md.
4. I switch to B.md tab.

Now the markdown preview tab switches to B.md and refreshes when I click on it. I would like to know a setting for VSCode to keep A.md in the preview tab and not auto-refresh.

Spent some time searching on SO and in VSCode user settings but cannot seem to find a relevant setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to use the command

```
markdown.showLockedPreviewToSide
```

You can find it in the command palette "`Markdown: Open locked preview to the side`") or as the command in the keyboard shortcuts - where you could set it to a keybinding, there isn't a default keybinding.

Comment: This indeed works. Furthermore, if someone wants to open the preview in the same editor group and not to the side, it is possible using the [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) extension. In your macro, you just need to combine `markdown.showLockedPreviewToSide` and `workbench.action.moveEditorToPreviousGroup` commands.